# Android Chart data

Tags: android, android-fragments

Im creating an android application which displays chart data in different fragments using view pager , i need to give onvalueselected in the graph so that i can display the corresponding data , and that is working but the data is getting displayed ie) the fragment is overlapped by the graph , i need the graph to close and only the data fragment to get displayed, here is my code

```
 @Override
  public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h)
  {
    Fragment fragment1 = new SlideFragment();

    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.slide3, fragment1, fragment1.getClass().getSimpleName()).addToBackStack(null).commit();`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand what you want to achieve , looks like you want to hide Chart when value is selected ? set visibility would not do ?

Comment: No i dont want to hide chart , It is a horizontal bar chart displaying values for a month , if i click on a particular date ie) the bar the separate fragment which displays data for that data comes up , actually it does come up but over the chart fragment . it is not getting closed on displaying another fragment @Du.Fantasy

Comment: you are saying your fragments get overlapping?@ Tamil Selvan

Comment: ya , yes exactly @Du.Fantasy

Comment: @Du.Fantasy I believe you put your comment here because you don't have an enough rep but please don't use the answer section for asking clarification, answere some other question that has clear problem statement and earn rep from it. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Ive Found the solution while Adding fragments over the fragments add  android:background="@android:color/white" in the xml file of the fragment so that the fragments wont overlap the other fragments